# Fetch only some parts of a large JSON in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder how to fetch only a part of large JSON file

In my example, its not that large but in my project the file is sometime like 7000 lines of code.
Example Json: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?expand=schedule.linescore

How to fech only the team Name for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, from a network request you only get what the server serves you. You can't fetch only a portion from that. You can process the data after the response from server, where you can refer to the portion of your data by key values. Like this.

```
response['totalItems']
```